# Do testimonials in a CV work?

Tags: resume, references

I have playing with the idea to add testimonials on my CV. The testimonials are mainly a few praises I received in my email from random people about open-source projects I have built that made their life easier.

The question is; how would a hiring manager or HR see this? Personally when I see testimonials they don't appeal much to me and seem a bit superficial but that might be different for others.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just suggest those people as referenceS, and let folks contact them if inclined to ask?

Comment: I've never heard of anyone doing that. Is it a US thing or am I just too green?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Testimonials are generally considered an extra on the CV, unless and until they are from someone really important.

For example, if I am the one hiring you, and you have a testimonial for an open source project, then this is how my evaluation goes:

If it's from someone important on that project like the maintainer or a notable person in that particular community:  **Yeah, you have managed to impress me**, cause such people rarely write testimonials, but when they do, it means that you have been very impressive.

Else,  meh.

Comment: +1. The only testimonial that would have any impact would be from a person that the hiring manager recognizes (and respects). Just including nice comments from random people is likely to be seen as artificial and odd on a CV/resume.

Comment: It's like adds for movies with quotes from random unknown critics websites, taken out of context.