# Would it look unprofessional to recommend someone in an unrelated field on LinkedIn?

Tags: professionalism, linkedin

I am currently a student looking for work in the field of science, while my friend is looking to get his photography work out there. We are both utilising LinkedIn for this purpose. My friend actually took my professional photo and I was thinking I could either give him a recommendation stating I was a client of his and he took my photo, or just add a note to my summary linking to who took the photo. Just to help get more people to view his profile and work.

I am wondering if this will seem unprofessional to employers? I doubt anyone would ask about my relation to him, but it may be strange that I would promote someone in an unrelated field (I believe it shows up on my profile if I recommend someone).

Comment: Unprofessional as per me. It won't carry much weight in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not unprofessional. You are in fact a client of his (I assume he did a good job) And there is nothing wrong with recommending him in that capacity.

Comment: I would also add, that no one is expecting students to make many recommendations based on the other person being a coworker or having some other professional relationship.

Answer (score 0):

what is an unrelated field? I am a computer programmer.

But if I write code for a satellite program... I can recommend an engineer.

If that satellite goes to Mars...I can recommend a biologist or a chemist.

But if that satellite goes to Pluto.. I can recommend a member of the [Rock and Roll Hall of Fame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_May#Astrophysics)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to include an [answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/57704/40657) which I wrote to a similar question:

> Testimonials are generally considered an extra on the CV, unless and
>   until they are from someone really important.
>
> For example, if I am the one hiring you, and you have a testimonial
>   for an open source project, then this is how my evaluation goes:
>
> If it's from someone important on that project like the maintainer or
>   a notable person in that particular community:  Y**eah, you have
>   managed to impress me**, cause such people rarely write testimonials,
>   but when they do, it means that you have been very impressive.
>
> Else,  meh.

So, it wouldn't be unprofessional, but they carry absolutely no or very *little to be taken seriously* weight